# How to run thread before third party function call concurently?

Tags: c++, qt

I have made a worker thread task and another is my public third party function.
I want to run both threading slot (e.g:StartWork())and my public function(e.g:on_pushButton_4_clicked()) concurrently, but they won't. Please give me any idea how to do that. here is my code:

Mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include "ui_mythread.h"
Mythread::Mythread(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Mythread)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //Debug
    this->dumpObjectInfo();
    //myWorker->dumpObjectInfo();
}

Mythread::~Mythread()
{
    myWorker->abort();
    WorkerThread->wait();
    qDebug()<<"Deleting thread and worker in Thread "<<this->QObject::thread()->currentThreadId();
    delete WorkerThread;
    delete myWorker;
    delete ui;
}
void Mythread::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "stopwork signal emmitted";
    emit stopWorkSignal();
}

void Mythread::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    myWorker = new worker;
    WorkerThread = new QThread;
    myWorker->moveToThread(WorkerThread);
    WorkerThread->start();

    connect(myWorker, SIGNAL(valueChanged(QString)),this, SLOT(myfunc(QString)));
    connect(WorkerThread, SIGNAL(started()), myWorker, SLOT(StartWork()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(stopWorkSignal()), myWorker, SLOT(abort()));
    qDebug()<<"inside work";
    int i =0;
    while (i<1000)
    {
    qDebug()<<":count *i=========>"<<i;
    i++;
    }
    return;
}

void Mythread::myfunc(QString s)
{
    qDebug()<<"thread TXT"<<s;
    //
    ui->label->setText(s);
}
```

worker.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"
#include<QDebug>
#include<mythread.h>

worker::worker(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    _working =false;
    _abort = false;
}

void worker::do_Work()
{
    qDebug() << "inside do Work";
    qDebug()<<"Starting worker process in Thread   "<<thread()->currentThreadId();
    for (int i = 1; i<100; i ++) {
    // Checks if the process should be aborted
    mutex.lock();
    bool abort = _abort;
    mutex.unlock();
    if (abort) {
        qDebug()<<"Aborting worker process in Thread "<<thread()->currentThreadId();
        break;
    }

    // This will stupidly wait 1 sec doing nothing...
    QEventLoop loop;
    loop.processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
    QTimer::singleShot(100, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();

     //Once we're done waiting, value is updated
    emit valueChanged(QString("%1").arg(i++));
    }

    mutex.lock();
    _working = false;
    mutex.unlock();

    qDebug()<<"Worker process finished in Thread "<<thread()->currentThreadId();
    emit finished();
}


void worker::abort()
{
    qDebug()<<"Stop Thread";
    mutex.lock();
    if (_working) {
    _abort = true;
    qDebug()<<"Request worker aborting in Thread "<<thread()->currentThreadId();
    }
    mutex.unlock();
    emit finished();
    //lbl->close();
    //lbl->deleteLater();
}
void worker::StartWork()
{
    qDebug() << "inside StartWork";
    _working = true;
    _abort = false;

    //emit running();
    do_Work();
}
```

output coming like this:

```
  :count *i=========> 988 
  :count *i=========> 989 
  :count *i=========> 990 
  :count *i=========> 991 
  :count *i=========> 992 

 thread TXT "1" 
 thread TXT "3" 
 thread TXT "5" 
 thread TXT "7"
```

Comment: Sir i want like output both threading and my public function would be at a time run but it is first public function running then thread starting .

Comment: There's a LOT of code here  - I would suggest that you trim it down to something minimal

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- You connect QThread::started to StartWork() **after** you started your thread, so it's likely that you miss the signal.
- Doing a while() loop of 1000 is something that is done in a very short time, so chances are that it will run before you get the chance to signal to the other thread.
- And the most important issue is that when you emit valueChanged() on the thread it will be queued to your main thread on myFunc().

And you can always call QThread::currentThread() to see if it's running on the right thread, it's also UP to the OS to schedule your threads so expecting to see output from both threads is unlikely to happen at the same time the way you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually i wants to display loading busy gif animation while main gui thread is busy so that's why i have done worker thread but problem is that when i am calling worker thread ,first my main thread task is working then my worker thread is running .

Comment: That's what you think is happening because the way you are trying to see it happening, since the signals you emit are queued on the event loop queue, and you print the thread changed values from the main thread, but the main thread is busy and is not returning to the event loop to process each valueChanged() signal.

Comment: In this case what i have to do ?i had checked by while loop but same issues coming .can you edit my code ?

Comment: The code you pasted here should have a processEvents() on the while loop, but that loop is also too fast so you should also have some kind of sleep. Another option is to print a debug message before you emit the value.